# How can I compare 2 LinkedLists but taking Object as parameter?

Tags: java

This is my school assignment. I don't know how to solve it because the method equals only allows passing one parameter. Please giving me some hints.

Here is the question:

Add the method public boolean equals(Object other) that returns true when the contents of 2 AList objects are the same. Note that 2 AList objects are the same if they have the same number of items and each item in one object is equal to the item in its corresponding location in the other object (15 points).

The method above must be added in LList2.java

AList class

```
public class AList<T> implements ListInterface<T> {
private T[] list;   // array of list entries
private int numberOfEntries;
private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 25;

public AList() {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY); // call next constructor
} // end default constructor

public AList(int initialCapacity) {
    numberOfEntries = 0;
    // the cast is safe because the new array contains null entries
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    T[] tempList = (T[]) new Object[initialCapacity];
    list = tempList;
} ......
```

LList2.java

```
public class LList2<T> implements ListInterface<T> {
private Node firstNode; // head reference to first node
private Node lastNode;  // tail reference to last node
private int numberOfEntries;

public LList2() {
    clear();
} // end default constructor

public final void clear() // NOTICE clear is not final in interface and that is OK
{
    firstNode = null;
    lastNode = null;
    numberOfEntries = 0;
} ......
```

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: Either you could override equals() method or use comparator

Comment: Follow the instructions, start by making a method that returns true if the sizes match, and false if they don't match, then expand that method to check for the size and the first element, then start using loops

Comment: @Ferrybig but when I type other.length(). It does not allow to call length() method to check its size

Comment: one more hint, search for instanceof` and casting

Comment: I downvoted because this is basically a "please do my homework"-Question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's an instance method - it compares the object passed as a parameter with the object it's being called on (aka `this`). Note that you don't explicitly need to call `this`, but I left it in there to make the code clearer:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    // Check that other is even an AList
    if (!(other instanceof AList)) {
        return false;
    }

    // If it is, cast it and compare the contents:
    AList otherAList = (AList) other;

    // Compare the lenghts of the arrays
    if (this.numberOfEntires != otherAList.numberOfEntries) {
        return false;
    }

    // Compare the contents of the arrays:
    for (int i = 0; i < this.numberOfEntries; ++i) {
        if (!this.list[i].equals(otherAList.list[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Didn't find a reason why the two aren't equal, so they must be:
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you should not do other guys homework... That is not StackOverflow's intention.

Comment: would be better to cast towards the interface instead of a specific implementation

Comment: @Wisthler That's a matter of decision. Should an `AList` and a `SomeOtherList` with the length and the same content be considered equal? If so, definitely use the interface. If not, you should stick to the concrete class. In any event, the casting should match the `instaceof` checking.

Comment: @Mureinik indeed it depends on the requirements. Which is not very clear in this context but reading between the line, the goal of the exercice is probably to do it a interface level